# How to use WIX CopyFile element to copy file on change/repair to a system folder without installing it to the target?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, file-copying

I have a problem which is related to the execution of CopyFile on change/repair when using WIX to make a msi setup.

I have a feature which has a component which copies/moves a file from the source folder to a folder already present somwhere inside a users system. It is not the folder of my application. I am only moving this file and not installing it to the the target. This feature works fine if I install it using a complete setup. But when on initial install I chose not to install this feature and then try to install it during a " change " all other custom actions/components inside the feature are executed/installed except for the CopyFile component. This is critical to my setup and if it does not get copied my setup will fail.

Just wondering if anyone found a solution to a similar problem or ever came across a similar issue?

Comment: Can you install the file into that location rather than copying it from another location?

Comment: yes I have given it a try and that is working. Until I or anyone else finds a solution I will use that approach but ideally I would like to prevent duplication in order to reduce the size of installation.

Comment: So you need the files in both locations, do you? WiX should handle this situation and keep only one version of the file in the CAB.

Comment: What do msi logs say in 'change' mode? There should be a reason why it skips copying this file.

Comment: The log file skips this whole step - without any info - when I try to use the Change mode. If I proceed the normal way it shows that it has actually moved the file. and yes I need the file in both locations but not in my TARGET DIR. If I had it over there as well then I would be keeping it at three locations.

Comment: I see. Is the target file the key file of a component in the added feature? When doing 'change' install, MSI checks for presence of the key files only. If the key file exists, then the component will be skipped. Did you use the verbose logs: `/lvx*`?

Comment: I don't have a File element in my component. I have only CopyFile inside my Component and I have set its attribute of KeyPath to yes. This component is packed with other components inside a feature. The feature references a Component which has key files which can get installed with other features.It looks a bit odd as during a Change my setupd will install all other components which have File in it but skips the one which only has a CopyFile and has its KeyPath set to "yes". I have tried verbose logging and it does not show that it is skipping the install. It just does not appears in it.

Comment: thanks anyway for looking into this :)

Answer (score 1):

The component which contains the CopyFile operation is configured incorrectly. It should have an actual file or registry entry as a key path.

Although Windows Installer uses components to manage resources, the component key path is main factor which decides if the component is installed or not.

So a component without a resource as a key path will never be installed and the CopyFile operation it contains will never be executed.

Comment: I have placed the file in this component and it works this way. But the thing is that it duplicates this file which I was trying to avoid initially. I have also set KeyPath attribute to true. I will try to place the registry entry with CopyFile and see if that works. Will report soon.

Comment: I tried following with no luck
<Component Id="copyComponent" Guid="GUID">
 <CopyFile Id="File2Copy"  SourceName="File.ext" SourceProperty="SourceDir" DestinationProperty="DEST"/>          
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software" Action="create">
            <RegistryKey Key="productKey" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
              <RegistryValue Action="write"  Name="KeyName" Type="integer" Value="0" KeyPath="Yes" />
            </RegistryKey>
        </RegistryKey>
</Component>